# How to correctly set the Uri of an image from a folder selected by the user to show in an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, uri

I need to display an image which I know the file name but I don't know the folder, which must be specified by the user.

I use `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);` to get the folder from the user. It returns an Uri with a path along these lines:

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload

Now I need to display an image from this folder in an ImageView. I tried the following:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), 
Uri.parse(chosenFolder + "/image.png"));
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageview);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The first line throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload/image.png

Replacing `%3A` by `:` doesn't work.

How to correctly set the Uri to display the image?

Comment: the image you want to show is the one picked from the gallery right ?

Comment: No, the user only chooses the folder. I have the image names on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve what I wanted with an InputStream.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

To work, the `imageUri` must be an Uri along the lines of:

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Download/image.png

However, this means you will be accessing files you do not have permission by default. This means you will have to deal with getting permission.

This is not what I wanted so I scrapped this approach.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use `file path` and not `URI` . A `content://` `Uri` does not have to represent a file on the filesystem .

try this :

```
String filePath = null;
if (chosenFolder != null && "content".equals(chosenFolder.getScheme())) {
    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(chosenFolder, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();   
    filePath = cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();
} else {
    filePath = chosenFolder.getPath();
}
```

and then create bitmap with file path :

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), 
Uri.parse(filepath+ "/image.png"));
```